# How to resize a photo?

Tags: photo-editing, resolution, rescaling

I know this is really a noob question, but it has always confused me. If something says "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide." how do I do that? I assume one uses a program to do it, but which program? Or maybe just cropping?

I know this is similiar to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23591/how-to-resize-an-image-for-web-display)

but I am not a programmer. The difference between that question and mine in that I need the answer in not-a-programmer language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a copy of your file, do not resize your original photo.

You can use this free program: http://www.gimp.org/

### Using Gimp:

1. Open your file.
2. Use the rectangle select tool. (Define some initial dimensions to set the  proportion you need) Move it, scale if from the corners to mantain the proportion and frame your image.
3. Menu > Image > Crop to selection.
4. Now resample. Menu Image > Scale Image. (Use "Cubic" on the quality interpolation section)
5. Apply a slight sharpen. Menu > Filters > Enhance > Sharpen.

### Using Photoshop

(You could use a program like photoshop, but do not spend on a trivial task like this one)

1. Open your file
2. Touch the select tool. Define your proportion.
3. Define on your image the area you like. Scale it and frame it.
4. Right Click on it. Crop.
5. Now Resample. Menu > Image > Size. Use the Bicubic or Bicubic Sharper.

Comment: a suggestion would be to add a Lightroom section as its not the same as PS and PSE.

Comment: Even Paint has a crop function nowadays. Open, make selection, crop, done.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used IrfanView http://www.irfanview.com it has an option to resize an image to a specific width and height, it also provides lots of other image related functions and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a mac user? if yes then preview provide a really easy way to apply resizing (even on many at once) on image(s).

Just follow this process:

1. Open your image in *Preview*
2. Go to tools Select *Adjust Size* [image]
3. Now in opened window you will have several options that you can use as
   per your requirements [image]

Click unlock in you don't want to resize in ratio.